# How to use geonames API to get city name?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, geonames

How can i search the geonames using their API and get city name and coordinates?
Link to their [API](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it depends entirely on the actual search you want to perform. Let's say you want to find all locations in Great Britain that start with `Lon`. The URL that will perform this search (as an example, much may change for a real search) is:

```
http://api.geonames.org/search?name_startsWith=lon&country=GB&maxRows=10&username=demo
```

You can pop that in your browser and see the results:

```
<geonames style="MEDIUM">
<totalResultsCount>334</totalResultsCount>
<geoname>
    <toponymName>London</toponymName>
    <name>London</name>
    <lat>51.50853</lat>
    <lng>-0.12574</lng>
    <geonameId>2643743</geonameId>
    <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
    <countryName>United Kingdom</countryName>
    <fcl>P</fcl>
    <fcode>PPLC</fcode>
</geoname>
<geoname>
    <toponymName>Lone</toponymName>
    <name>Lone</name>
    <lat>58.33333</lat>
    <lng>-4.88333</lng>
    <geonameId>2643732</geonameId>
    <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
    <countryName>United Kingdom</countryName>
    <fcl>P</fcl>
    <fcode>PPL</fcode>
</geoname>
<!-- and so on ... -->
</geonames>
```

Note that you want the `lat` and `lng` elements under each `geoname`. With LINQ to XML (include `System.Linq` and `System.Linq.Xml` in your namespace declarations):

```
var xml = XElement.Load("http://api.geonames.org/search?name_startsWith=lon&country=GB&maxRows=10&username=demo");

var locations = xml.Descendants("geoname").Select(g => new { 
                    Name = g.Element("name").Value, 
                    Lat = g.Element("lat").Value, 
                    Long = g.Element("lng").Value
                });

foreach (var location in locations)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}", location.Name, location.Lat, location.Long);
}
```

Of course you may choose to use these values differently, and you may want to parse `Lat` and `Long` into doubles.